# BM_GETCHECK not working

Tags: c++, winapi

I have code like this :

```
In WM_CREATE

    hCheckBox = CreateWindowEx(0,"Button","Random text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS| BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_TEXT | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,150,323,300,20,hwnd,0,hInstance,0) ;


In WM_COMMAND

    if ( SendMessage( hCheckBox , BM_GETCHECK, (WPARAM) NULL, (LPARAM) NULL ) == BST_CHECKED )
        MessageBox( 0, "Working", "Msg", 0 );
```

Doesn't matter if the checkbox is checked or not, it never return BST_CHECKED.
Trying to make it work for the last 2 hours :(

Comment: There's no obvious problem with what you've posted, but what is the SendMessage() call actually returning?

Comment: What is `WM_CREATE{...} WM_COMMAND{...}` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Herr the SendMessage() is returning BST_UNCHECKED irrespective to the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

It is not entirely apparent whether `hCheckBox` is a local automatic variable. If so, I can assure you it is not holding its value from the time the `CreateWindow` fires until the time the WM_COMMAND message is received. Use this instead:

```
LRESULT chk = SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
```

Where `hDlg` is your dialog or main window handle, and `IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID` is the control ID. To that, you need to specify the control id as a non-zero value for the HMENU parameter to your create-call:

```
hCheckBox = CreateWindowEx(0,"Button","Random text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS| BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_TEXT | WS_GROUP |
    WS_TABSTOP,150,323,300,20,hwnd, IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID, hInstance,0);
```

And in case it wasn't obvious. Define IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID as a non-zero integer.

---

**EDIT**

Assuming the control is setup correctly, you should be able to handle the WM_COMMAND for this checkbox as follows in your WndProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowExA(0,"Button","Random text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
            WS_CLIPSIBLINGS| BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_TEXT | WS_GROUP |
            WS_TABSTOP,100,100,300,48, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID, hInst, 0);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

        // Parse the menu selections:
        if (wmId == IDC_CHECKBOX_CTRL_ID)
        {
            if (wmEvent == BN_CLICKED)
            {
                LRESULT chkState = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
                if (chkState == BST_CHECKED)
                    MessageBoxA(hWnd, "Checkbox is checked!", "CheckBox", MB_OK);
            }
            break;
        };
        // fall-thru intentional

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I just slammed this into a stock generic WIN32 app with a blank window. the results are in the image below:

[image: Results of checking the checkbox]

Comment: My code is valid, i just typed it in hurry just to show what call goes where. No, hcheckbox is not local, it is created in WM_CREATE but the variable is global. I tried SendDlgItemMessag, but it too didn't work.

Comment: @StudentX Did you set the child control id in your `CreateWindowEx` call ?

Comment: Yes I did set the control id

Comment: @StudentX since I can't see your *real* code the best I can do is show you what I know works. See the WndProc in this answer for an implementation on a generic window that creates a checkbox, and throws up a messagebox in response to the check state.

Comment: I am doing exactly like that. Yet nothing. I checked with the button click message of the checkbox itself both messagebox with "checked" and "checked again" shows; else if ( (HWND)lParam == hCheckBox )
     {
          MessageBox( 0, "Checked", 0 , 0 );
          if ( SendMessage( hCheckBox, BM_GETCHECK, (WPARAM) NULL, (LPARAM) NULL ) == BST_CHECKED ) // checkbox selected
          {
              MessageBox( 0, "Checked again", 0 , 0 );
          }
     }